# Java JSON library throwing exception

Tags: java, json, org.json

I have the following JSON string:

```
{"widget":{"order":{"fizz":["23", "55"],"setting":"always"}},"resp":"ok"}
```

And the following Java code:

```
try {
    JSONObject json = getTheAboveStringAsJSON();
    order = json.getJSONObject("order");
} catch(JSONException e) {
    throw new RuntimeExcept(e.getMessage());
}
```

Giving me the following exception:

```
JSONObject["order"] not found.
java.lang.RuntimeException: JSONObject["order"] not found.
```

What's going on here? Why the exception? What can I do to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: coz `order` is a level down from the top of the object. e.g. `$json->widget->order`, not `$json->order`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your structure is

```
{
    "widget":{
        "order":{
            "fizz":["23", "55"],
            "setting":"always"
         }
     },
     "resp":"ok"
}
```

So you need to first access "widget", and then "order" within the widget

```
order = json.getJSONObject("widget").getJSONObject("order")
```

Answer (score 0):

what ever the json data returning by getTheAboveStringAsJSON() method there is no data with

order `key`

```
json.getJSONObject("widget").getJsonObject("order");
```